# Remove characters from string (DataFrame)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How do I remove extra characters with **REGEX** in this string code snippet below.

**From This :**  Fulham\n3.20\nDraw\n3.25\nSouthampton\n2.25\n

**To Desired Outcome:** 3.20\n\n3.25\n\n2.25

*Note*: I've tried with this regex -> ([^\d.\n])  but it leaves unwanted 'n' in team name if applicable.

```
([^\d\.\\n])

Fulham\n3.20\nDraw\n3.25\nSouthampton\n2.25\n
```

Comment: Why would you tag this with `web-scraping`?

Comment: @baduker It's a cleaning exercise from a dataset. Thought web scraping would apply. I can remove if you recommend

Comment: @HedgeHog Thank you for the edit. Learning everyday...will get there :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
s = "Fulham\n3.20\nDraw\n3.25\nSouthampton\n2.25\n"
"\n\n".join(i for i in s.split() if re.search(r"\d", i))
```

Output:

```
'3.20\n\n3.25\n\n2.25'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `str.replace`.

```
df['column_name'].str.replace(r'[a-zA-Z]','')
```

*If you don't need the trailing and leading `\n` you can then use `strip('\n')`*